# changing window.location.hash creates entry in history but doesn't affect chrome back button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser-history, html5-history

**Update :-** As `Akansh Gulati` Pointed out in his answer if user have any interaction with the page before clicking back button this will work as expected and if user do not have any interaction with the page and press back button then any entry in history ( either by hash-change or by history.push/replace ) will be ignored which is part of [Google Chrome update will stop websites hijacking your browser back button](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1344199)

This is valid and logical answer so I am accepting his answer

---

I am trying to show a success popup after page load and if user press android back button ( which is in this case equivalent to browser back button ) I only want to close the popup ( don't want to redirect back on payment page )

I am adding hash in url when popup is open but when user press back button chrome ignore the hash and redirect back on previous page instead of just removing the hash ( working fine in Firefox )

<s>I have a working example [here](https://www.tripurari.in)</s> use following HTML code to reproduce

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body onload="test()">
    <button type="button" onclick="window.history.back();">Back</button>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function writeLength() {
      document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(window.history.length));
    }

    function test() {
      window.location.hash = 'a';
      setTimeout(function() {
        writeLength();
        window.location.hash = 'b';
        setTimeout(function() {
          writeLength();
          window.location.hash = 'c';
          setTimeout(function() {
            writeLength();
          }, 1500);
        }, 1500);
      }, 1500);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

a) open this page in chrome

b) wait till hash is changed to '#c'

c) then press browser back button

expected behavior is it should change the hash back to '#b' and then back to '#a'
but it ignore all the hash changes and redirect back to new-tab page

This is the [code](https://github.com/tripurari001/tripurari001/blob/f8e84e47972ff61129710b93dbe87a77e01af415/index.html#L15-L26)

```
      window.location.hash = 'a';
      setTimeout(function() {
        writeLength();
        window.location.hash = 'b';
        setTimeout(function() {
          writeLength();
          window.location.hash = 'c';
          setTimeout(function() {
            writeLength();
          }, 1500);
        }, 1500);
      }, 1500);
```

how can I simulate the correct behavior (if there is any way) ?

I am using chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Mac

here is a GIF image of behavior

[image: actual behavior GIF image]

Comment: Works as expected (from reading the code) for me in Chrome 77. Please clarify your expectation and add your Chrome version. Consider also adding a screencast and try to paraphrase at what point the unexpected behavior happens/starts.

Comment: @try-catch-finally I have added a GIF of actual behavior

Comment: Weird. That looks indeed wrong and not what I can observe when testing this.

Comment: your working example worked as intended for me (Brave v0.70.100).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried using pushState for further location changes and the problem seems solved. No need to replaceState. The condition is only that user must have clicked/interacted atleast once with screen.

```
function test() {
        window.location.hash = 'a';
        setTimeout(function () {
            writeLength();
            window.history.pushState(null, null, `${window.location.pathname}#b`);
            setTimeout(function () {
                writeLength();
                window.history.pushState(null, null, `${window.location.pathname}#c`);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    writeLength();
                }, 1500);
            }, 1500);
        }, 1500);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

In this browser you need to explicitly set at least one state in the History through the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) (not sure why though).

<sub>The example should work even in this iframe.</sub>

```js
history.replaceState( {}, '' );

window.location.hash = 'a';
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log( location.hash );
  window.location.hash = 'b';
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log( location.hash );
    window.location.hash = 'c';
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log( location.hash );
      console.log( "You can now use your browser's back button" );
      onpopstate = e => console.log( location.hash );
    }, 150);
  }, 150);
}, 150);
```

Comment: Uh? Tested it in various places with three different versions of Chrome on macOS and Android with incognito mode on and off and it always works. Are you saying that the example in the answer doesn't work when you press "Run code snippet" then back button? [Here is a plnkr with your exact code and the fix](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/xi7e0Seyg976SyWRagOA?p=preview&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=worker&utm_campaign=next&preview), can you confirm this doesn't work for you? @TripurariShankar

Comment: this link on plnkr is working fine but when I impliment same logic in my website and open it directly in chrome it doesn't work
tried things like passing 2nd argument null and empty string in pushState but no luck

Comment: So your implementation of my answer doesn't work. You probably didn't copy correctly? (Note that using replaceState is actually a better idea, I did update my answer)

Comment: super weird sometime it works sometime it doesn't same happens when I increase the set-timeout delay

Comment: I cannot reproduce the (original) error on my system (Linux + Chrome 77, no addons) - it is functional. You should not claim that this `replaceState()` workaround is required in Chrome without understanding the underlying issue. And obviously its not reliably reproducible yet.

Comment: @try-catch-finally I can reproduce 100% of the time on both my macOs and Android settings, and my workaround workarounds 100% of the cases. I think I am in a better position to tell if this workaround works than you who are not able to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your state explicitly, and you can execute some code when you click the back button, like this:

Add a function to get the `window.location.href` without the hash part (because we will add it explicitly):

```
function getUrlWithoutTheHash() {
    let url = window.location.href;
    let hash = window.location.hash;
    let index_of_hash = url.indexOf(hash) || url.length;
    return url.substr(0, index_of_hash);
}
```

Add a function to push state (rather than changing the hash using the location, we change it using the state API) and we will add an attribute `is-my-state` to the state to know if this is our state or not:

```
function pushTheState(url) {
    history.pushState({'is-my-state': true, 'url': url}, null, url);
}
```

And add a handler when you open the state, and if this was one of your states, you can execute a desired code:

```
window.onpopstate = function(e){
    if(e.state){
        if(e.state.hasOwnProperty('is-my-state')){
            writeLength();
        }
    }
};
```

Finally, you need to change your function like this:

```
function test() {
    pushTheState(getUrlWithoutTheHash() + '#a');    // pushing url with #a
    setTimeout(function() {
        writeLength();
        pushTheState(getUrlWithoutTheHash() + '#b');    // pushing url with #b
        setTimeout(function() {
            writeLength();
            pushTheState(getUrlWithoutTheHash() + '#c');    // pushing url with #c
            setTimeout(function() {
                writeLength();
            }, 1500);
        }, 1500);
    }, 1500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get the code your provided working on the same version of Chrome on Windows 10, but if you're still having issues the following should work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body onload="test()">
    <div id="url"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="window.history.back();">Back</button>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){
      document.getElementById('url').innerHTML = window.location.href;
    }, 500);
    function writeLength() {
      document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(window.history.length));
    }
    function test() {
      history.pushState({},'','#a');
      setTimeout(function() {
        writeLength();
        history.pushState({},'','#b');
        setTimeout(function() {
          writeLength();
          history.pushState({},'','#c');
          setTimeout(function() {
            writeLength();
          }, 1500);
        }, 1500);
      }, 1500);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

This should work because `window.pushState` should force the hash change to be added to the browser's history. If you want to update the page of a navigation change, you can use the `window.onpopstate` event. For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body onload="test()">
    <div id="url"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="window.history.back();">Back</button>
    <span id="lengths"></span>
</body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){
      document.getElementById('url').innerHTML = window.location.href;
    }, 500);
    var last = false;
    var items = [];
    function writeLength() {
    items.push(window.history.length);
       document.getElementById('lengths').appendChild(document.createTextNode(window.history.length));
    }
    function test() {
     history.pushState({},'','#a'); 
      setTimeout(function() {
        writeLength();
        history.pushState({},'','#b');
        setTimeout(function() {
          writeLength();
          history.pushState({},'','#c');
          setTimeout(function() {
            writeLength();
            last = true;
          }, 1500);
        }, 1500);
      }, 1500);
    }
    window.onpopstate = function(){
      if (last) {
        if (window.location.hash == '#a') document.getElementById('lengths').innerHTML = items[0];
        else if (window.location.hash == '#b') document.getElementById('lengths').innerHTML = '' + items[0] + items[1];
        else if (window.location.hash == '#c') document.getElementById('lengths').innerHTML = '' + items[0] + items[1]+ items[2];
      }
    }
  </script>
</html
```

The code above allows the user to navigate to different "states" of the page after the final length has been written to the document.